# How do you get my rails radio_button_tag to save the data on form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I am newer to rails and thought I would add a radio button set to a form to enforce user choice.  I am able to get the form loaded and select one of the options, but upon posting via the submit button I get a model error for the field needing to be present (something I am wanting to validate). Below is my form code for the radio buttons.

```
<div class="field">
  <div>
  <%= f.label "Type" %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= radio_button_tag :ptype, "Question" %><%= label_tag :ptype_question, 'Question' %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= radio_button_tag :ptype, "Problem" %><%= label_tag :ptype_problem, 'Problem' %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= radio_button_tag :ptype, "Idea" %><%= label_tag :ptype_idea, 'Idea' %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= radio_button_tag :ptype, "Praise" %><%= label_tag :ptype_praise, 'Praise' %>
  </div>
</div></br>
```

I've whitelisted :ptype in the params within the controller, so I know that isn't the issue, and when I make the field just a plain text_field I am able to submit just fine, so I am thinking I messed something up with the multiple options, but haven't quite been able to figure it out even after checking a few other posts.

I also noticed it is getting the data in the logging, but it isn't indented like the other elements which are:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
authenticity_token: 7uAQ/Wx4...
post: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  title: Packers
  content: Rock!
  category: Football
ptype: Question
commit: Post
controller: posts
action: create
```

Again, thinking it's a simple fix since the text_field posts fine, but still too new to figure out quite what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your full `form` code along with with `strong_params` method?

Comment: it is because your other fields for post like title or content. there tags you are displaying like f.text_field but for ptype you are using radio_button_tag. radio_button_tag does not assosiate field to model itself. try this         radio_button_tag "post[ptype]", "Praise"

Comment: why can't you use `f.radio_button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply form object to radio button like this:

```
f.radio_button
```

it will submit without any mess.